# Very simple MongoDB & ASP.Net Website setup hangs on Find() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm just trying to get a small MongoDB example working in an ASP.Net website, and for some reason I don't get anything back when I call the Find() method on a collection.

I have the service running in a command line window on the default port. If I call the find method from another command line window, then it works fine:

[image: working]

Here's my controller code (I know this is not great code I'm just trying to get it working):

[image: code]

When I run the site in debug mode, it comes into the private method, connects fine...

[image: connected successfully]

But then when it hits the Find() method, it just hangs seemingly forever (I've left it for a good 5 minutes). I get no timeout, or errors, or exceptions, or anything.

I followed the tutorial on the site pretty closely, but am all out of ideas for what to try next. Anyone got any ideas? Would be much appreciated, thanks! (sorry if this is something really simple and obvious! Feels like it probably is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're implementing a synchronous action and blocking it while calling the asynchronous `FindPlayers` method.

You should replace controller action's signature to `public Task<ActionResult> Index()` and refactor its code to:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    // This will free up request thread and it will return to the thread
    // pool until FindPlayer() Task ends, and it will reclaim a thread
    // to continue with returning the view.
    await FindPlayers();

    return View();
}
```

Finally, you should rename the method to `FindPlayersAsync`, since the convention for asynchronous methods is `[Name of method]Async` and it makes easier to discover if a method is synchronous or asynchronous just by its identifier.

Learn more about asynchronous actions [with this official ASP.NET web site tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'm not sure I understand why though. Is it not possible to have the controller method wait until mongo's Find() method on the collection completes?

Comment: @JD41 You're doing that with `await`. Why don't you read this wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O

Comment: "It seems like you're implementing a synchronous action and blocking it while calling the asynchronous FindPlayers method."

What I'm saying is, what's wrong with doing that? I understand it may not be best practice, but shouldn't it still work? From what I can understand from the articles, FindPlayers should wait on Find().FirstOrDefault(), but then when it gets a result from that, it should complete and the synchronous action should become unblocked. Instead I just saw the debugger hang on the Find().FirstOrDefault() line seemingly indefinitely.

Comment: @JD41 It's how web host works. It would be hard to explain here in a simple comment, but blocking the request has side effects and instead of trying to workaround them, you should go the non-blocking I/O way which gives you the same result but it provides performance improvements

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Thanks for the reply!